# MySQL: delete rows returned by subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to remove rows where there is a duplicate `link` column from a table. I'm trying to run:

```
delete from resultitem 
       where id in (select r.id 
                    from resultitem r 
                    group by r.link
                    having count(r.id) >1);
```

But getting an error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'resultitem' for update in FROM clause
```

Is this possible to remove rows by subquery in MySQL without a temporary table?
Please advise.

Comment: It looks like your trying to remove all entries where there is a duplicate, not just the duplicate entries. Is that your intention?

Comment: @podiluska yeah, exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should delete all but the lowest `id` per `link`:

```
delete  ri1
from    resultitem as ri1
inner join
        resultitem as ri2
on      ri1.link = ri2.link
        and ri1.id > ri2.id
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2877a/1/0)

To remove all duplicate links, leaving none of the duplicates behind, remove the `and ri1.id > ri2.id`.

Comment: The same issue: You can't specify target table 'r1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: MySQL syntax is always surprising.  The edited version should work, tested on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE resultitem
FROM resultitem
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) as RowId, link
   FROM resultitem
   GROUP BY link
) as KeepRows ON
   resultitem.id = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
delete r from resultitem r
INNER JOIN (
       (select id 
                    from resultitem rr 
                    group by rr.link
                    having count(rr.id) >1) rr
ON r.id = rr.id;
```

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON r.id = rr.id'

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from resultitem 
       where id not in (select r.id  
                  from (select r1.id, unique(r1.link) from resultitem r1) as r );
```

Comment: Syntax error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unique(r.link)
from resultitem r )' at line 1`